# Как распарсить текст с филды Selenium2.0 Juinit

Tags: junit, selenium-webdriver

Пишу автоматические тесты на джаве, столкнулсся с проблемой. Определенные шаги приводят к тому что в поле появляется линка, мне надо забрать эту линку и перейти по ней с помощью команды driver.get("String");
Если кто сталкивался подскажите плиз

P.S.
Линка должна производить автоматическую авторизацию

Comment: Тебе надо кликнуть по этой линке или же забрать оттуда какой-то аттрибут, который будет являтся ссылкой, и уже перейти по этой ссылке?

Comment: Забрать оттуда, а потом скопипастить. Собственно я уже справился с поможщью команды .getText

Comment: тогда ответь на свой вопрос и пометь его как правильный